# Why is nth-child selector not working in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using the `nth-child` selector to add border-color for different social `list-group-item`. What am I doing wrong?

```css
    .list-group-item:nth-child(1) {
     border-right: 3px solid yellow;
    }
    
    .list-group-item:nth-child(2) {
     border-right: 3px solid red;
    }
    
    .list-group-item:nth-child(3) {
     border-right: 3px solid green;
    }
    
    .list-group-item:nth-child(4) {
     border-right: 3px solid blue;
    }
    
    .list-group-item:nth-child(5) {
     border-right: 3px solid lime;
    }
    
    .list-group-item:nth-child(6) {
     border-right: 3px solid red;
    }
```

```html
   <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
     <div class="views-field views-field-title">
      <span class="field-content list-group-item">Yahoo<a href="/app/wall/content/"></a></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
     <div class="views-field views-field-title">
      <span class="field-content list-group-item">Googke<a href="/app/wall/content/"></a></span>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Target the parent element and then descend. https://jsfiddle.net/139gs7tp/1

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want the border on the `<a href="/app/wall/content/"></a>` OR the parent of that anchor element?, as it stands you have the anchor element here methinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nth-child` counts in relation to its parent, and `.list-group-item` is the only child of its parent in your example. You could change this in a variety of ways, including by counting the outermost elements as shown here.

```css
.new-class:nth-child(1) .list-group-item  {
    border-right: 3px solid yellow;
}

.new-class:nth-child(2) .list-group-item  {
    border-right: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 new-class">
    <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content list-group-item">Yahoo<a href="/app/wall/content/"></a></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 new-class">
    <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content list-group-item">Googke<a href="/app/wall/content/"></a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using drupal.

Answer (score 0):

The selector works by referring to direct children of an element in terms of order. Above, you're attempting to select children of the span tags declared to use the list-group-item class, which don't exist.  Try instead the nth-of-type() selector on the nearest common parent of all the div elements containing the span tags that you wish to style.  Something like the following would probably work:
     #container span:nth-of-type(1) {
     ...
     }